# Converting a String[] of Amazon S3 object keys to a treemap/ hashmap etc

Tags: apache-flex, grails, groovy

Feel im being a little dense on this one, would be great if you could help me out.

I am currently pulling data from an s3 storage account. S3 has a flat file structure but gives the impression that the files are stored in directories.

So the question is, how do I convert this String[]

```
[ 
  "/company_1/user_1/1.txt",
  "/company_1/user_1/2.txt", 
  "/company_1/user_1/3.txt",
  "/company_1/user_1/4.txt",
  "/company_1/user_2/5.txt",
  "/company_1/user_2/6.txt",
  "/company_1/user_3/7.txt"
]
```

into a hashmap like this

```
[
  name : "company_1", 
  children: [
              [
               name : "user_1",
               children : [
                             [name : 1.txt],
                             [name : 2.txt],
                             [name : 3.txt],
                             [name : 4.txt]
                          ]
              ],
              [
               name : "user_2",
               children : [
                             [name : 5.txt],
                             [name : 6.txt],
                          ]
              ],
              [
               name : "user_3",
               children : [
                             [name : 7.txt],
                          ]
              ],

           ]
]
```

I am using grails to render the data as JSON for a flex application using an Advanced Datagrid and need a tree like structure, as if you were browsing files on your desktop.

What is the most grooviest way of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to get this into a map (not the format you wanted, but a map all the same), is to do something like:

```
String[] example = [ 
  "/company_1/user_1/1.txt",
  "/company_1/user_1/2.txt", 
  "/company_1/user_1/3.txt",
  "/company_1/user_1/4.txt",
  "/company_1/user_2/5.txt",
  "/company_1/user_2/6.txt",
  "/company_1/user_3/7.txt"
]
example*.tokenize( '/' ).groupBy( { it[ 0 ] }, { it[ 1 ] } )
```

That gives you the map:

```
[
  "company_1": [
    "user_1":[
      ["company_1", "user_1", "1.txt"],
      ["company_1", "user_1", "2.txt"],
      ["company_1", "user_1", "3.txt"],
      ["company_1", "user_1", "4.txt"] ],
    "user_2":[
      ["company_1", "user_2", "5.txt"],
      ["company_1", "user_2", "6.txt"] ],
    "user_3":[
      ["company_1", "user_3", "7.txt"] ]
  ]
]
```

obviously, it requires a bit more work to get it into the format you specified :-/

#### edit

Think I got it...

```
def crunch( k, v ) {
  ( v instanceof List ) ?
    [ name:k, children:v.collect { [ name : it[ -1 ] ] } ] :
    [ name:k, children:v.collect { k2, v2 -> crunch( k2, v2 ) } ]
}

def rsltList = example*.tokenize( '/' ).groupBy( { it[ 0 ] }, { it[ 1 ] } ).collect { k, v ->
  crunch( k, v )
}
```

means that `rsltList` is a List containing:

```
[
  [ "name":"company_1",
    "children": [
      [ "name":"user_1",
        "children": [
          [ "name":"1.txt" ],
          [ "name":"2.txt" ],
          [ "name":"3.txt" ],
          [ "name":"4.txt" ] ] ],
      [ "name":"user_2",
        "children": [
          [ "name":"5.txt" ],
          [ "name":"6.txt" ] ] ],
      [ "name":"user_3",
        "children": [
          [ "name":"7.txt" ]]]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks tim_yates, I think this could give me something to work with.

Comment: @juk3sie Watch out in your original JSON specification, you have `[ name : 5.txt, name : 6.txt ]` which will obviously give you problems having two items with the same key

Comment: Thanks, that was an error in me writing the question, it would be `[name : 5.txt], [name : 6.txt]`, I'll edit.

Comment: @juk3sie think I got a solution to the code...  I prefer the JSON from the first version though ;-)  Good luck!

Comment: @juk3sie glad to help (ps: I removed the debug lines I left in by mistake) ;-)  whoops!